# How to get the type of non-static method without instance?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, c++17, function-pointers

I am trying to create a template function in C++ like:

```
template<typename IteratorType>
double evaluate(const IteratorType &rBegin, const IteratorType &rEnd,
    double(*function)( const decltype( *IteratorType ) &rObject )) // error, typename not allowed
    // I'm unsure if I need to put the reference there, not part of the problem.
{
    // ...
} 
// not my actual code, just to show an example.
```

Though this does not work since I need an instance of a `class`/`struct` to call a non-static method,
which I can't do since it's in a function.
After googling around a bit I found this solution:

```
double(*function)( const typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorType>::value_type &rObject )
```

Though as you can see this gets clumsy to use (and is a pain to change), especially when you are trying to create multiple overloads. This also did not seem to work for my iterators, so after a while I realized this:

```
double(*function)( const typename IteratorType::value_type &rObject)
```

would be the best solution.

In the end I realized there was no guarantee for "`IteratorType`" to have `value_type` defined as the type of the value, and that pointers are a thing.

Is there any way for me to get away with something along the lines of

```
double(*function)( const decltype(*IteratorType) &robject)
```

?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the error message in the question

Comment: your question is difficult to follow, but my guess is that you are looking for `std::iterator_traits<IteratorType>::value_type`

Comment: @idclev 463035818 I'm pretty sure I included a minimal reproducible example, and "std::iterator_trais<IteratorType>::value_type" is already in the question.

Comment: oh I realized you already used iterator traits, whats wrong with them?

Comment: *"`iterator_traits` ... This also didn't seem to work for my iterators"* It means your iterators are written incorrectly, see [iterator requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

Comment: no thats not a mcve, firstly I dont know what compiler error you get, but i am certain that it isnt the one I get when I try to compile it:https://godbolt.org/z/YkcEZU

Comment: "n the end I realized there was no guarantee for "IteratorType" to have value_type defined as the type of the value, and that pointers are a thing" thats why you should use iterator traits...

Comment: How is extracting `value_type` from an iterator related to calling non-static functions? The problem with `decltype(*IteratorType)` is that it usually will give you the `reference_type`, not the `value_type`. The `std::iterator_traits` approach looks like the only generic solution. If you'd show more context, someone might hint you how to reduce some "clumsiness" from that.

Comment: @chtz the problem with `decltype(*IteratorType)` is that it doesn't work since it usually isn't a static method, so I would need an object to get the type. I'm unable to retrieve an object since its in a function.

Comment: @Theoul I see. You are looking for [`declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) (in your case this won't be less clumsy than the `iterator_traits` solution, though).

Comment: @Theoul The alter native to `decltype(*IteratorType)`, you need `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*rBegin)>`. Or use `std::declval`. BTW, things could have been more clearer, if you would have put some actual code, rather than talking in air.

Comment: @Const you mean my actual code?

Comment: @Theoul The **Minimal, Reproducible Example** would contain a class and its static member function and your demonstration, how you make a template function for that static member.

Comment: @Const aah I see, didn't think that was relevant

Comment: @Theoul Did you read the link on the first comment? Providing a [mre] will avoid a lot of unnecessary discussion.

Comment: @chtz I'm pretty sure I did, though I thaught those parts weren't actually relevant to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need a minimal example to your problem. Here is what I understood from your comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct MyClass /* final */
{
    static double member(std::string const& val) /* noexcept */
    {
        std::cout << "double MyClass::member(int val): " << val << "\n";
        return {}; // return appropriate results
    }
};

template<typename IteratorType>
void evaluate(IteratorType rBegin, const IteratorType rEnd,
 // WHAT??? other than:
 // double(*function)(const typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorType>::value_type &rObject )
{
    while (rBegin != rEnd)
    {
        function(*rBegin);
        ++rBegin;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec{ "1", "2", "3"};
    evaluate(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), &MyClass::member);
}
```

---

> Though as you can see this gets clumsy to use [...]

In addition to *[@Const's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62549227/c-get-type-of-non-static-method-without-instance/62549392#62549392)*, if your problem is to use `std::iterator_traits`, you have following two other options.

- **Option - I**

  Like *[@chtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870253/chtz)*
  mentioned in the comments, use
  [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)
  to get the underline type of the iterators as follows:

  ```
  template<typename IteratorType>
  void evaluate(IteratorType rBegin, const IteratorType rEnd,
   double(*function)(
   std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::declval<IteratorType>())> const&))
   //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--> value_type == std::string 
  {
      // ... code 
  }
  ```

  Providing a helper template type alias wouldn't be a bad idea there:

  ```
  template<typename IteratorType>
  using ValueType = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::declval<IteratorType>())>;

  template<typename IteratorType>
  void evaluate(IteratorType rBegin, const IteratorType rEnd,
     double(*function)(ValueType<IteratorType> const&))
     //                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value_type == std::string
  {
     // ... code
  }
  ```

  **([See live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Hh-HCw))**
- **Option - II**

  From the `rBegin`, by converting the `T&` to `T` using
  [`std::remove_reference_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference).

  ```
  template<typename IteratorType>
  void evaluate(IteratorType rBegin, const IteratorType rEnd,
     double(*function)(std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*rBegin)> const&))
     //                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ---> std::string
  {
     // ... code
  }
  ```

  **([See live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/SEKo4y))**

Answer (score 4):

> Though as you can see this gets clumsy to use [...]

Provide some template aliases and you could reduce the clumsiness!

```
template<typename IteratorType>
using ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorType>::value_type;

template<typename IteratorType>
using FunctionPtr = double(*)(const ValueType<IteratorType> &);

template<typename IteratorType>
double evaluate(const IteratorType rBegin, const IteratorType rEnd,
    FunctionPtr<IteratorType> function)  // now you can simply this
{
    
}
```